# thread priority and functions execution time

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli, execution-time

I have a function let's call it foo() that performs some operations on matrices.
If I call the function in a console application it needs 1 second to return the results.
if I call it in a Windows form application (button click, start a new thread, call foo() from the thread), the function needs 3 seconds to return. with the same inputs, and the same outputs obviously.
I think it is because the thread handling the windows form is still active, how do I stop it, or slow down it giving less priority?

Comment: well I use c_clock to measure the time to compute the function, no idea how to measure the time spent by thread handling the form, since I don't know how to access that thread, that's why I "think"

Comment: I mean to use a profiler. Measuring with `clock` will be very imprecise, since .NET does many things behind your back which can spoil such simple measures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you would want to kill the form event thread. That would render your application unusable. That thread is not running computationally intensive tasks anyway, it's waiting for events on the form, so there is little to gain from setting the priority to low.

Please specify how exactly you are measuring the time it takes the thread to finish. There are certain overheads associated to starting/stopping threads that would not appear in your console application.

Comment: I'm doing like this: clock_t finish(clock()); foo(); clock_t finish(clock()); int n=finish-start; in the case of console the value is around 1000, in windows form is around 3500. that sounds really strange to me. the function is really the same, I added a Thread called by the button click... and that's it

Comment: How do you signal the 'n' out of the thread and display it, or you stopping the thread on a debugger break and inspecting it after it is calculated?  The value should be the same, as hinted at by @Tudor - it's the same core-type doing the same work.  In 1000-3000 processor ticks, you would be unlucky to find that foo() was interrupted by anything and I'm sure you've done the test more than once. Once started by any thread, it's very likely that foo() would just run until the return and second clock_t call.

Comment: well I found that a function defined in opencv library take 4 times more in windows form than in console. I just rewrote the function and the performance are almost the same.